# How to emplace derived object into map

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm still new to C++ and have come across a problem where I can't seem to insert a new derived class to a map.

My code is simplified as follows:

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Base_Class> > m;

void func(){
  for(int num = 0; num < 100; n++){
    m.emplace(num, new Derived_Class() );
  }  

}
```

Which gives me this:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::pair <const int, std::unique_ptr<Base_Class> >::pair(int&, Derived_Class*)
```

I've tried unsuccessfully using:

```
m.emplace(std::pair(num, new Derived_Class()) );
```

And which gives me this:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<Base_Class> >::pair(std::pair<int, Derived_Class*>)
```

I can't seem to figure this one out and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7):

```
m.emplace(num, std::unique_ptr<Derived_Class>(new Derived_Class()));
```

Would be the way to go. Since the `unique_ptr` constructor taking a raw pointer is explicit, it cannot be implicitly initialized from a `Derived_Class*`. You need to explicitly create a `unique_ptr` object to emplace.

I posed this solution because you mentioned [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), but the truly favorable way would be to use `std::make_unique<Derived_Class>()` ([c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) and onward), both to avoid repeating yourself, and to make the creation of the unique_ptr "atomic".

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. That worked. May I ask why this is necessary when I was able to use similar code with the vector container? - Edit: I did indeed come across the std::make_unique solution only to learn I could not use in C++11 which is why I felt necessary to include it in the title. Thanks again!

Comment: @dyrandal - A map's value type is a `std::pair<>`, while a vector's is what it says on the tin. The initialization proceeds differently in those two cases, as is customary for C++ and it's many definitions of initialization.

Comment: @dyrandal - `make_unique` can be written in C++11 too. Many would use their own version prior to C++14 standardizing it. If you can include a homebrew version for it in your project, it would still be worthwhile.

Comment: That makes sense about the initialization process. And yeah, I actually did come across something like what you mentioned about implementing a custom make_unique, but I wasn't able to make full sense of it why I needed it. I'm still wrapping my head around all the details of move/copy semantics. Does it speed up execution in a similar way to emplace/emplace_back?

Comment: @dyrandal - Not everything is about execution speed. This is about managing resources. Up until C++17, the compiler can interleave expression evaluations in function calls. For instance `unique_ptr<A>(new A), unique_ptr<B>(new B)` at a function call, can be executed by first doing `new A` and `new B` and only then initializing the `unique_ptr` objects. So if `B` throws when constructed, the `A` leaks. But if it all happens inside an easily inlinable function, then no interleaving may happen, and so neither will a leak.

Comment: Another option that may (or may not) be worth mentioning is `m[num].reset(new Derived_Class());`. Although it is slightly different in that it will always replace an existing element's target.

Comment: @Galik - If `Derived_Class` throws in its constructor, we get a null pointer added regardless.

Comment: Getting the wrong result quickly is as useful as it sounds.

Comment: @user4581301 - I'd expect the exception being thrown to be a better indicator of things gone wrong. I wouldn't want to mutilate the map as well.